# Novel about 4 children who are the "beta" group, and have to keep taking pills in order to keep their memories

Tags: story-identification, dystopia

I'm trying to find a dystopian novel I've read a few years ago.

It's about 2 boys and 2 girls who need to take these pills or injections to stay alive or keep their memory, and they're called the beta group or something like that. They get confronted by the alpha group, which they realize are basically clones of all four them.

One of the guards takes away their pills so the beta group will forget everything but one of the members of the beta group still has pills and since the guards are watching, they pass the pills through their mouths by kissing. I don't remember the rest.

Comment: When exactly was "few years ago"? In which language/country did you read this? Do you remember anything else about the plot?

Comment: Like 2008. I was in the United States and the book was in English. That's all I remember about the plot.